# Stop weblogic server forcefully using command line

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I want to shutdown weblogic server using command line FORCEFULLY. I have a specific scenario. I have written a batch file to do some stuff and then shutdown weblogic server using `stopWebLogic.cmd` as follows:

```
"%WEBLOGIC_DOMAIN_PATH%\bin\stopWebLogic.cmd"
```

I have gone through [this](http://xmlandmore.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-force-shutdown-weblogic-managed.html) document. But I can't follow the approach since I don't want to change `stopWebLogic.cmd`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

A WLST script is probably the way to go.  See the [shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13813/reference.htm#WLSTC454) command which has an optional 'force' parameter.

N.B. On UNIX/Linux you can send a SIGTERM signal to the pid of a weblogic server which will perform a force shutdown.  i.e. kill -term *pid*

Comment: The `stopWebLogic.cmd` in turns calls this: `echo shutdown^('%SERVER_NAME%','Server', ignoreSessions='true'^) >>"shutdown.py"`. I can add a force parameter here and it will work. But I don't want to go on every weblogic setup and modify `stopWebLogic.cmd`. And I must call this cmd file since it does many other things than just calling shutdown command.

Comment: Hmm, what else does your stopWebLogic.cmd do?  The only 12c domain I have to hand is a SOA Suite one which the only additional thing it does is to shutdown the Derby database if it's being used.

The only approach I can think of is to call a custom shutdown wlst script from your batch file.  Since the commands are wlst online this doesn't have to run on the same server as your domain, although if you do, you don't need to provide credentials in the connect() call.  Instead you specify adminServerName and boot.properties is used instead.  This is how the stopWeblogic.cmd script does it.

Comment: WLST is your best bet outside of a kill or modifying stopWebLogic. Maybe you can clarify the question but you're going to have to write/modify SOMETHING to do this

Comment: @JeremyGosling Yes the additional thing `stopWebLogic.cmd` does is shutting down derby database. Maybe I can write a WSLT script to achieve this. The only thing is I will need to maintain this script in future (in case the shutdown logic changes in future releases). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @castling My only concern was not changing `stopWebLogic.cmd`. But I wanted to use it with some CL parameter or flag  to achieve forceful shutdown. If it's not possible, I can obviously modify/write something on my own. I was just looking for best possible way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an existing file if you configure it to force the shutdown

head to `bin/stopWebLogic.sh`

Then modify the following line

```
echo "shutdown('${SERVER_NAME}','Server', ignoreSessions='true')" >>"shutdown.py"
```

to

```
echo "shutdown('${SERVER_NAME}','Server', ignoreSessions='true', force='true')" >>"shutdown.py"
```

Then execute the file using `bash stopWeblogic.sh`

The weblogic will be stopped, even if active sessions or listeners exist.